# App crashes when back button is pressed, using cursor loader

Tags: java, android, mobile

So I loaded all my images using a cursor loader, and transferred those images into an adapter(adapter used by a gridview). I implemented an on-click listener on the gridview, which will display the image in a new activity.

All of that is working fine, however, when I press the back button, I expect to go back to my main activity(gridview with all the images), but my app crashes.

Here are some details.

Oncreate Method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // The gridview, and the image adapter is set up here.
    setupViews();

    // Once runtime permission is given, image paths are
    // 1. pulled into a cursor,
    // 2. added onto the imageAdapter
    // 3. and the imageAdapter is set to be used by the gridview.
    askForRuntimePermission();
}
```

askForRuntimePermission and onRequestPermissionsResult (Callback Method).

```
private void askForRuntimePermission() {

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
    else
    {
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(MEDIASTORE_LOADER_ID,null,this);


    }

}

/**
 * Callback method for request permmissions method.
 * @param requestCode
 * @param permissions
 * @param grantResults
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch(requestCode)
    {
        case STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE:
            if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(MEDIASTORE_LOADER_ID,null,this);

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Implementing Cursor Loader.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {
   String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
   return new CursorLoader(this,
           MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
           projection,
           null,
           null,
           MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    *transferImagesToAdapter(cursor);*
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader) {

}
```

The transferImagesToAdapter method is where I transferred and set up the gridView with its adapter, displaying the images on the grid.

However, as mentioned, after clicking any image, it will appear full screen on a new activity, but when the back button is pressed, the app crashes.

Any help?

Comment: Hey Ryan, could you also post the error showing on the logcat when the app crashes, that could assist greatly

Comment: Hi guys, I just used an async task instead.